# Unexpected result from VHDL design

Tags: vhdl, waveform

It should output value of `Qpl` when all inputs are `x` and `clk = 1` but it does not. What is the problem with the following code;

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--This is a D Flip-Flop with Synchronous Reset,Set and Clock Enable(posedge clk).
--Note that the reset input has the highest priority,Set being the next highest
--priority and clock enable having the lowest priority.
ENTITY syn IS
    PORT (
        Q : OUT std_logic; -- Data output
        CLK : IN std_logic; -- Clock input
        Qpl : IN std_logic;
        RESET : IN std_logic; -- Synchronous reset input
        D : IN std_logic; -- Data input
        SET : IN std_logic -- Synchronous set input
    );
END syn;
ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF syn IS --architecture of the circuit.
BEGIN
    --"begin" statement for architecture.
    PROCESS (CLK) --process with sensitivity list.
    BEGIN
        --"begin" statment for the process.
        IF (CLK'EVENT AND CLK = '1') THEN --This makes the process synchronous(with clock)
            IF (RESET = '1') THEN
                Q <= '0';
            ELSE
                IF (SET = '1') THEN
                    Q <= D;
                ELSE
                    Q <= Qpl; 
                END IF;
            END IF; 
        END IF;
    END PROCESS; --end of process statement.
END Behavioral;
```

Following diagram is showing the waveform of the above design, and desired operation requirements;
[image: waveform]

Comment: Note that `SET` is not a good choice for applying `D`. Like "reset" sets a register to '0', "set" normally sets a register to '1'. Usual names are "load" or "enable". I think "load" is the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the waveform diagram, it seems that everything works alright, when the input signal `SET` becomes `U`, the if condition cannot be evaluated, thus the output `Q` also becomes as such, namely `U`. You can see while `SET` was `0`, the output `Q` was getting the value of `Qpl` correctly.

[image]

Sorry for the crude drawing, but you can see at the circled clock rising while `SET` is `0`, `Q` gets the value of `Qpl` as expected. Only after `SET` signal becomes `U`, the output `Q` also loses its value in the next clock rising event, and also becomes `U`

Comment: So my code also correct for the question right?(above the waveform image)

Comment: Apart from `Qpl` part, you are not setting it, and the logic there is wrong. It shouldn't be an input signal, but a locally stored value -> you should have a variable `Qtemp`, and keep the value of `Q` within that while you are retaining the value, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14593941/3641067)

Comment: Probably this is gonna be a lot to ask but i dont know how to implent that stuff to my code.I am really new to this code language i dont know what to do even with your help

Answer (score 1):

You code and comments differ. As does the table/diagram. A D-flipflop/register is a very simple component. Example:

```
entity dff is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        set : in std_logic;
        load : in std_logic;
        d : in std_logic;
        q : out std_logic
    );

architecture rtl of dff is
begin
    dff_proc : process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst='1' then
                q <= '0';
            elsif set='1' then
                q <= '1';
            elsif load='1' then
                q <= d;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```